# Existe um proverbio em português nos moldes de "a procissão ainda não saiu da igreja"? É arcaico ou ainda é usado?

Tags: proverbios

Eu hoje li, em outro site, a citação de um provérbio português que seria traduzido como "a procissão ainda nem saiu da igreja".  Esse provérbio, ou ditado, ainda é de uso corrente em Portugal?  É usado no Brasil? O significado não é difícil de perceber embora, pessoalmente, eu nunca tenha ouvido. Imagino que seja bem antigo, visto que procissões já "saiíram de moda" há muito tempo aqui no Sudeste do Brasil.

Comment: Talvez exista uma versão mais longa: "a procissão ainda nem saiu da igreja e nem sequer chegou ao adro" ([fonte](https://www.record.pt/opiniao/escrevem-os-leitores/detalhe/sera-que-a-procissao-ainda-nem-saiu-da-igreja-e-nem-sequer-chegou-ao-adro); adro: pátio, "espaço descoberto na frente [...] das igrejas").

Comment: @stafusa, esse exemplo parece ser único e uma elaboração de *a procissão nem saiu da igreja* influenciada por *a procissão ainda vai no adro*. E é uma elaboração mal pensada: se dissesses *a procissão não saiu do adro, nem sequer ainda da igreja*, ainda vá, mas se não saiu do igreja, é óbvio que não pode ter chegado ao adro (o adro é fora da igreja).

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo, do ponto de vista lógico é um mau complemento (ou há procissões que partem da igreja?). Se ainda por cima não está em uso nem há registro anterior, seria o caso de remover meu comentário inicial.

Comment: @stafusa, não vejo necessidade de retirar o comentário: foi a tua primeira ideia. As procissões mais comuns são no fim da missa: abre-se a porta principal, o pessoal sai e vai formando a procissão no adro. Creio que naquele exemplo, é um título de artigo, o autor simplesmente quis reforçar a versão tradicional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, [sendo eu o “culpado”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577483/possible-meanings-of-they-are-forming-a-procession-in-the-square-in-context), tenho de responder. É bem conhecida em Portugal a frase feita ***a procissão ainda vai no adro***, significando ’isto é só o começo, vem aí muito mais do mesmo’. O [*adro* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/adro) é um espaço aberto em frente à igreja, onde normalmente começam as procissões. A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/prociss%C3%A3o) dá uma definição ligeiramente diferente:

> diz-se quando queremos dar a entender que os factos sucedidos não passam do prólogo de outros mais graves que hão de suceder

Isto parece-me demasiado restritivo: provavelmente usa-se a frase sobretudo acerca de coisas más, mas não tem de ser assim. *A procissão ainda nem saiu da igreja* eu não conhecia, mas encontra-se com o mesmo significado na imprensa portuguesa recente, e a variante *ainda a procissão não saiu da igreja* ao que parece já vem [num livro de 1981](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ainda%20a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20n%C3%A3o%20saiu%20da%20igreja%22&biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&ei=fD95Ydf5BKiSxc8PiK25mAg&oq=%22ainda%20a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20n%C3%A3o%20saiu%20da%20igreja%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14219.19973.0.20661.14.14.0.0.0.0.119.1371.9j5.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.dzRSdz-VPA0) (o Google não mostra o conteúdo). A frase tradicional já vem do século XIX, mas continua perfeitamente atual. Exemplos:

> A bravata da defunta [Aliança Democrática] está a produzir cada vez mais vítimas. […] Alguém nos diz que “**ainda agora a procissão vai no adro**” e mais vitimas vão surgir
> [Público, 15-4-1999](https://www.publico.pt/1999/04/15/jornal/e-se-passassemos-a-gostar-do-portas-132142)
>
> […] tudo isto, dizia, determinou a multiplicação dos estudos sobre o salazarismo — e a **procissão ainda vai no adro**.
> [Análise Social, 1984](https://books.google.pt/books?id=546nAAAAIAAJ&q=%22e%20a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20ainda%20vai%20no%20adro%22&dq=%22e%20a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20ainda%20vai%20no%20adro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj-M6AjerzAhXjEWMBHXv8CcQQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

Aqui encontrei uma elaboração que nunca tinha ouvido, apropriada para quando alguém quer fazer algo antes de tempo, parece-me; algumas procissões levam da igreja uma estátua de algum santo, que no fim é posto de novo no altar:

> — Quer isso dizer que não tencionas viver um dia com ele?
> — Caramba mulher. Isso é o que eu chamo pôr o carro à frende dos bois. Pois se **a procissão ainda agora vai no adro** já tu queres meter o santo no altar?
> [Manuela Inês, 2013](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kFWRqxImiy4C&pg=PA26-IA2&dq=%22a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20ainda%20agora%20vai%20no%20adro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq0tyDjurzAhWR3eAKHXYBBZ0Q6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20prociss%C3%A3o%20ainda%20agora%20vai%20no%20adro%22&f=false)

### No Brasil

Vendo as coisas aqui de Portugal, quer-me parecer que no Brasil a frase sempre foi rara, se não praticamente desconhecida. Vi tudo quanto *vai no adro* (desde 1800) na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx) e encontrei apenas oito exemplos, sendo cinco de correspondência de Portugal e apenas três de produção local brasileira: um no [Jornal do Comércio (1978)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=170054_01&Pesq=%22vai%20no%20adro%22&pagfis=173525) de Manaus, e um n’[*O Dia* (1924)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=092932&pesq=%22vai%20no%20adro%22&pasta=ano%20192&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=2012) e outro na [*Última Hora* (1964)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=830348&pesq=%22vai%20no%20adro%22&pasta=ano%20196&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=19254) de Curitiba:

> Escrevemos nos primeiros dias deste ano que [??] seria marcado pela  agudização da divergência franco-americana. **Ainda a procissão vai no adro** e já o sr. Truman acha dever botar palavra. A que não iremos assistir daqui a meses quando Washington começar a sentir os efeitos da política externa francesa de que se apercebe ainda difusamente?
> [Vitor Rego, “Truman e a dívida histórica”, *Última Hora*, Curitiba, 3-3-1964](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=830348&pesq=%22vai%20no%20adro%22&pasta=ano%20196&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=19254)